# How to deal with questions that need more information that in the question proposed as a duplicate

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, specific-question, exact-duplicates

[This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/263901/42221) was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/164936/42221). Although the questions share the last part of the answer, answering the newer question requires information that is not in the original answer.  Also, because of the way the original question was asked, the missing information doesn't belong in the original answer. The new question asker needs to know that "some sort of dot pivot" is in fact the "Object Origin" being discussed in the original question.

It doesn't make sense to edit the original question and add definitions -- we'd have to do that with nearly every accepted answer, so if for no other reason, it's not practical.

It doesn't make sense to point the person asking the new question to the old question -- they don't know what "object origin" is.

It doesn't make sense to provide an answer that defines object origin and then directs the OP to a different answer that has so little new information.

So why doesn't it make sense to leave the question?

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case the appointed duplicate adequately addresses the question.

The fact that new users don't know the terminology doesn't warrant a new answer all together, and also doesn't mean the question is not a duplicate regardless.

If one factors explaining terminology into an otherwise duplicate question, there is no end to potential combinations of possible issues and technical terms. There would hardly be any two exact duplicate.

New users aren't expected to know all the technical terms, even veterans often call the same thing by different names. Provided these aren't deleted by the system, this also benefits SE in general, having these questions around about the same thing but worded differently, using unofficial terminology or "newb language" may help future users in a similar situation, which are likely to resort to the same type of language or descriptions rather than find out on their own the correct technical terms.

In cases like this I think posting in the comments section enlightening about the correct terminology, or pointing to an answer that addresses that would suffice.

[What are the small orange dots which appear next to a selected object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234221/what-are-the-small-orange-dots-which-appear-next-to-a-selected-object)

[What is this dot? Not fireflies question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129954/what-is-this-dot-not-fireflies-question)

Maybe additionally even factor it into the original post by editing it, without actually replacing completely the original wording, so that the indexing engine considers both when someone searches in the future.

Comment: If I understand how StackExchange works, one problem is that if a question is closed, a new user won't have sufficient reputation to see it, so it won't turn up in a search.  Linking the questions doesn't help new users because of this.  We're still stuck with the problem that if they don't know what to search for they can't find the existing answer, and so it may as well not exist.

Comment: As far as I know The OP will always be able to see his question and comments on it, so it will still help him at least. In this case the question has a positive score and answers with votes, so as far as I know all users will be able to see it in the future. Questions with low activity may vanish into the black hole of system routines though, not sure exactly how those work